# .htaccess / DENY FROM ALL / не запрещать доступ к файлу при submit запросе на него

Tags: .htaccess, сервер, безопасность, доступ

Установил запрет на доступ к файлам (несколько php файлов в ней) в папке через htaccess Dent from all. Однако, если в одном из этих файлов, находящихся в этой папке, совершается запрос через кнопку submut, то доступ остается закрытым для действий в файле обработчике. Например, в папке лежат два файла 1.php и 2.php . В 1.php есть форма, которая по нажатию на кнопку submit, отправляет данные в файл-обработчик 2.php. Так вот при deny all доступ к 2.php из 1.php запрещен. Как оставить папку закрытой от всех, но разрешить выполнять submit запросы?

Comment: сделать allow конкретно для этих файлов пробовали?

Comment: @AliVeliyev тогда любой человек, написав прямой адрес урл на этот файл, сможет получить к нему доступ. А этого мне не нужно

Comment: так а в чем проблема сделать защиту в самом файле? мол если это post запрос с такими то заполненными параметрами, или user agent потыкать?

Comment: смотрите, а запрос не через ajax? если просто стандартная сабмит, то можно сделать к файлу с формой include 2.php и сабмитить себя же с условием и получится норм